# Sum computed but not stored. Why?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I've started learning functions in C today. My issue in the function "sum" where I += numbers from arrays, it does write the sum of the numbers but when the program comes out of that "sum" function the integer where I save the sum of these numbers resets to 0 and I can't seem to figure out why.
This is the code, I sure do hope that you can help me out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
void arr(int hello[], int size) {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        hello[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
void print(int hello[], int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << hello[i] << " ";
    }
}
int sum(int hello[], int size, int sumup) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        sumup += hello[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Sum of these numbers: " << sumup << endl;
    return sumup;
}
int SumEvenOrOdd(int sumup, int size) {
    int average = sumup / size;
    cout << "Average of the all numbers in array: " << average << endl;
    return average;
}
int main() {
    bool bye = false;
    const int size = 10;
    int hello[size], sumup = 0, input;
    arr(hello, size);
    print(hello, size);
    sum(hello, size, sumup);
    SumEvenOrOdd(sumup, size);
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `sumup` in params?

Comment: This is C++, not C.  Editing tags to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the formal parameter `sumup` in the `sum` function is a different object from the actual parameter `sumup` in `main`, so any changes to `sumup` in the function are not reflected in `sumup` in `main`.

There are several ways to get around this:

1. In C++, you can define the `sumup` parameter in `sum` to be a *reference* to the `sumup` variable in `main`:

   ```
   int sum( int hello[], int size, int &sumup )
     {
       // leave everything else the same.  
     }
   ```

   In both C and C++, you can define the `sumup` parameter in `sum` to be a *pointer* to the `sumup` variable in `main`:

   ```
   int sum( int hello[], int size, int *sumup ) // leading * is necessary
   {
     ...
     *sumup += hello[i]; // leading * is necessary
   }

   int main( )
   {
     ...
     sum( hello, size, &sumup ); // leading & is necessary
     ...
   }
   ```

   Assign the result of `sum` back to `sumup` or to a different variable:

   ```
   int newsum = sum( hello, size, sumup );
   ```

   although then the question becomes, why pass `sumup` as an argument in the first place?  Just declare a local variable within `sum` to hold the value, and return that:

   ```
   int sum( int hello[], int size )
   {
     int result = 0;
     for ( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
       result += hello[i];
     return result;
   }

   int main( )
   {
     ...
     int sumup = sum( hello, size );
     ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Very nice explanation! Passing `sumup` value could be to start adding from that value.

Answer (score 1):

Change your line `sum(hello, size, sumup);` to `sumup = sum(hello, size, sumup);`. Then your return value will be saved in the variable sumup.

If you don't want to save your sumup variable via the return value, you should learn about call by reference (and how it differs to call by value). Then you could write to the function parameter sumup and change the original value instead of the local copy inside the function.

This will open the can of worms of pointer manipulation. One of the biggest sources of FUN with C ;-)

Example: https://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-call-by-value-or-call-by-reference

Answer (score 0):

Pass the function arguments as references so they can be accessed:

```
void sum(int hello[], int size, int& sizeup)
```

this will allow sizeup to retain it's value outside of the function since you're passing a reference of sizeup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

`sumup = sum(hello, size, sumup);`

You should get right sumup value.

Answer (score 0):

The function `sum` returns a value without a variable that will accept it. 
change this line:

```
   sum(hello, size, sumup);
```

to:

```
   int my_sum = sum(hello, size, sumup);
```

Then you will be able to use my_sum in your main.

Another solution can be passing `sumup` to your function by reference, just change the decleration to:

```
 void sum(int hello[], int size, int & sumup)
```